# "TypeError: <class 'numpy.typing._dtype_like._SupportsDType'> is not a generic class" when importing the plotly.express library

Tags: python, plotly

I want to create a simple plotly chart from a .csv file that I fetched from an API.

I import the library, pass the dataframe, and get the error:

```
TypeError: <class 'numpy.typing._dtype_like._SupportsDType'> is not a generic class
```

code:

```
import plotly.express as px

df=pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

What might be the problem, and what does this error mean?

Full error traceback:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_9952/1054373791.py in <module>
      1 from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output
----> 2 import plotly.express as px
      3 import pandas as pd

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\express\__init__.py in <module>
     13     )
     14 
---> 15 from ._imshow import imshow
     16 from ._chart_types import (  # noqa: F401
     17     scatter,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\express\_imshow.py in <module>
      9 
     10 try:
---> 11     import xarray
     12 
     13     xarray_imported = True

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from . import testing, tutorial
      2 from .backends.api import (
      3     load_dataarray,
      4     load_dataset,
      5     open_dataarray,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\testing.py in <module>
      7 import pandas as pd
      8 
----> 9 from xarray.core import duck_array_ops, formatting, utils
     10 from xarray.core.dataarray import DataArray
     11 from xarray.core.dataset import Dataset

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\duck_array_ops.py in <module>
     24 from numpy import where as _where
     25 
---> 26 from . import dask_array_compat, dask_array_ops, dtypes, npcompat, nputils
     27 from .nputils import nanfirst, nanlast
     28 from .pycompat import cupy_array_type, dask_array_type, is_duck_dask_array

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\npcompat.py in <module>
     70         List[Any],
     71         # anything with a dtype attribute
---> 72         _SupportsDType[np.dtype],
     73     ]
     74 except ImportError:

~\anaconda3\lib\typing.py in inner(*args, **kwds)
    273             except TypeError:
    274                 pass  # All real errors (not unhashable args) are raised below.
--> 275             return func(*args, **kwds)
    276         return inner
    277 

~\anaconda3\lib\typing.py in __class_getitem__(cls, params)
    997         else:
    998             # Subscripting a regular Generic subclass.
--> 999             _check_generic(cls, params, len(cls.__parameters__))
   1000         return _GenericAlias(cls, params)
   1001 

~\anaconda3\lib\typing.py in _check_generic(cls, parameters, elen)
    207     """
    208     if not elen:
--> 209         raise TypeError(f"{cls} is not a generic class")
    210     alen = len(parameters)
    211     if alen != elen:

TypeError: <class 'numpy.typing._dtype_like._SupportsDType'> is not a generic class
```

Comment: Pandas has already been imported, right?

Comment: @r-beginners Yes.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error, it is dependency issue, plotly.express (5.9.0) is not working with numpy==1.20, if you upgrade numpy==1.21.6 it will solve your error.

```
pip install numpy==1.21.6
```

Comment: This seems to be a bug in xarray actually: [xarray 2022.6.0 doesn't work well with numpy 1.20](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/6818). Possibly another solution would be to downgrade xarray.

Answer (score 1):

I was having same issue when I updated xarray. I tried updating numpy but conda environment was restricting it. Updating the whole conda environment helped me resolve this error.

```
conda update --all
```

Answer (score 0):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_4960/3694415272.py in <module>
----> 1 plotly.express.__version__

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\importers.py in __getattr__(import_name)
     37             return getattr(class_module, class_name)
     38 
---> 39         raise AttributeError(
     40             "module {__name__!r} has no attribute {name!r}".format(
     41                 name=import_name, __name__=parent_name

AttributeError: module 'plotly' has no attribute 'express'
```