# Numpy is Not a Generic Class

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I am trying to learn Python and following along some modules. I am using Anaconda Powershell Prompt and using Python 3.7 from there. I am trying to follow along via the code below.

Everything works until I get to the line

```
from wrf import getvar
```

When I do that line I receive this

```
>>> from wrf import getvar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Paul\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wrf\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import api
  File "C:\Users\Paul\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wrf\api.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .config import (xarray_enabled, disable_xarray, enable_xarray,
  File "C:\Users\Paul\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wrf\config.py", line 62, in <module>
    _init_local()
  File "C:\Users\Paul\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wrf\config.py", line 52, in _init_local
    _try_enable_xarray()
  File "C:\Users\Paul\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wrf\config.py", line 17, in _try_enable_xarray
    from xarray import DataArray
  File "C:\Users\Paul\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import testing, tutorial
  File "C:\Users\Paul\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\testing.py", line 9, in <module>
    from xarray.core import duck_array_ops, formatting, utils
  File "C:\Users\Paul\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\duck_array_ops.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import dask_array_compat, dask_array_ops, dtypes, npcompat, nputils
  File "C:\Users\Paul\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\npcompat.py", line 72, in <module>
    _SupportsDType[np.dtype],
  File "C:\Users\Paul\anaconda3\lib\typing.py", line 275, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Paul\anaconda3\lib\typing.py", line 999, in __class_getitem__
    _check_generic(cls, params, len(cls.__parameters__))
  File "C:\Users\Paul\anaconda3\lib\typing.py", line 209, in _check_generic
    raise TypeError(f"{cls} is not a generic class")
TypeError: <class 'numpy.typing._dtype_like._SupportsDType'> is not a generic class
```

Looks like the last few lines return an error but as a beginner I have zero clue what this means.

Comment: The picture isn't showing cause you removed the formatting for it. But either way, [please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] for more tips.

Comment: This seems to be a bug: [xarray 2022.6.0 doesn't work well with numpy 1.20](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/6818). I don't use xarray myself so I'm not confident enough to post an answer, but you might try upgrading NumPy or downgrading xarray.

Comment: Thank for for the feedback regarding the formatting of my post. I did some work with downgrading xarray and unfortunately that did not work :( 

It's not totally necessary I get this working. I'm just trying to learn Python (with my focus on meteorology) and I just have no clue where to start. There is so much info online but can't seem to find an excellent intermediate starters guide.

Comment: After doing some additional work the problem seems to definitely be with xarray

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a similar error to [<class 'numpy.typing._dtype_like._SupportsDType'> is not a generic class when importing the plotly.express library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73286085/2038264) - an incompatibility between `wrf-python` and `numpy`.

Try upgrading those libraries to the latest versions.

Comment: I have tried this as well and unfortunately that did not work